# Do arduino librarys require the arduino to be connected to a computer?

Tags: library

The title pretty much explains my question. If I'm using a library for example one for an accelerometer does the arduino need to be connected to my computer because it's using a library? Or is the library uploaded to the arduino and there for can run with out a computer connected?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Arduino libraries (strictly speaking only the utilized parts) are permanently built-in parts of your compiled sketch.  Effectively they are "statically linked" unlike the situation with modern RAM-based computer operating systems where compiled dynamic link library code may be separately loaded into memory for a program to call at runtime.

(This isn't even really a design choice, as the basic AVR Arduino's cannot load new program code into executable memory at runtime anyway - except by reflashing themselves like the bootloader does, which would be a bit slow compared to normal dynamic linking)

Of course if you have a library which is intended to perform *communication* with a computer, then that connection would probably be required for it to fully operate.